# download a SharePoint file to a specific folder on the local computer using c# and CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, file

I try to download a online file programmatically, which is stored in a document library to a local folder.

I know that I need to open a stream and then copy the stream to the local drive, but I'm a little stuck here.

My code is so far:

```
if(streamItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
{
    Url = new Uri(siteUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + streamItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;                    
    if(streamItem.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
    {                    
          Url = new Uri(siteUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + streamItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
             
          var fileRef = streamItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
               
          var fileName = streamItem.File.Name;
          var filePath = @"C:\Downloads\" + fileName;

          ClientResult<Stream> mstream = streamItem.File.OpenBinaryStream();
          context.ExecuteQuery();
               
          using (var fStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
          {
               mstream.Value.CopyTo(fStream);
          }                    
    }
}
```

I hope you can help or give me an hint.

Comment: what error you are facing here?

Comment: If I deploy it to Azure functions I get an error message 500 back, but I only want to download it to the local downloads folder. That's all.

Comment: @Matthias, I think your approach will not lead to your expected result. If you deploy this (or any piece of code) to Azure, then the code will not have access to your local drives. 

Unless I have misunderstood you...

Comment: I think you are right. What's a better approach? Could give me an example?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I needed to save it first locally and then later to download.